# How to update my Web App (chrome, mozilla, IE8+) changes without pressing ctrl+F5?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, caching, browser-cache

For example When I enter into my Gmail account I see changes every once in a while and those changes are effective without updating with ctrl+f5 (without cache data), the opposite happens with my web apps where the user has to press ctrl+f5 to see changes.

How can I achieve the same as other web apps that I see changes without the need to clear cache or update.

This issue is not with data but with html content. I load every section (js, css & html) with requireJS according to the AngularJS route, for example if I call index.php#/users/edit I load users/edit.html and so on, so when I make a change or add an HTML/CSS/JS file the changes are not visible even when pressing f5, the user needs to delete cache or press ctrl+f5

Comment: Are you asking about cache-busting URLs for resources, HTTP cache headers, or AJAX / WebSockets?

Comment: I have just added a response of your question in the explanation.

Comment: A bit confusing. Do you want something like a `push/self update service` (ie Gmail, Facebook, etc)?

Comment: Then you're asking about HTTP cache headers or cache-buster URLs.  See Wikipedia

Comment: @SLaks let me see about HTTP cache headers, the thing is that I am only using an index.html as the main layout (SPA) and other partes of the layout are being loaded as external files (html/css/js) so I think that I should set this headers in the index.html? is this achieved with meta-tags?

Comment: @Uuid: Cache headers apply to the resource being requested.

Comment: This is all about cache-bursting as XHR calls have their own cache header values and expiry time from Php. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understood your question correctly, what I usually do is append a 'version' parameter to the URL used to get page content.

Hence, instead of calling `users/edit.html` , you would request `users/edit.html?v=123`

You could have your version in a dedicated variable which you set either manually or at build time.

If you want to ignore the cache altogether you could append a random value using something like `Math.random()`

Comment: so what that this means?, is it that when I use a diferent parameter value on the  URL it will load the new content changes without clearing cache?

Comment: yes, that's how it *should* work. it will 'trick' the browser into thinking you're requesting another page